# What action Uber takes when the status of a ride does not change for a long time ? Does the action also generates a webhook callback?

Tags: uber-api

For eg: ride was in progress for 1 day ! Or ride was accepted, but neither the rider or driver, it any action on it. Does this generate webhook callback ?

I am using sandbox-api as of now. My ride just expires after some time(1 hour may be) and I get ClientError when trying to get the ride details. On rebooking, I get a new ride id. I do not know if webhook is firing callback or not, as I do not have a CA certificate as of now on my server listening to callback. Will this happen in production api also ?

Comment: I am using Python uber rides module. I get ClientError on trying to call get_ride_details function. I guess this should hit somewhere at the request endpoint .

Comment: Yeah I have request scope and the permission to access request scope. Will check ClientError Object.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately our sandbox isn't perfect and doesn't mimic production behavior 100%. In the production environment a trip in the "processing" stage is cancelled after around 2 minutes if no suitable driver is found.

Regarding the duration of a real trip...I don't think we have any hard limit on that. If the driver and passenger mutually agree to keep the trip going, then the trip keeps going.

Webhooks will be fire for all trip status changes (i.e "processing" to "accepted" etc)

Hope that helps!

Best, 
   Richie